# How to display multiple tags in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a add new user CARD which has a plus sign on it. I have made additional cards which display username on each card. The cards which display username are displayed using `.map()` method. Now if I insert part 1 code (see below) inside the `.map()` function then it displays multiple add new user card. My final goal is to display single add new user card and use `.map()` to display remaining cards.

#### Part 1 code:

```
<div className="item-card add" onClick = {this.addUser} >
  <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon"/>
  <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
</div>
```

If I insert above code inside `.map()` it displays multiple add new user card.

**Where should I insert the part 1 code inside `displayUsers()` method ?**

```
displayUsers() {
  return this.state.userList.map(user => {
    return (
      <div className="item-card">
        <div className="info">
          <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="del-wrap">
          <img src={require('../../images/cancel.svg')} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the Add user card separate from map render.

In version `16.2.0` or above you can return multiple elements by wrapping them in a `React.Fragment`

```
displayUsers(){

    return (
       <React.Fragment>
        <div className="item-card add" onClick = {this.addUser} >
           <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon"/>
           <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
       </div>
      {this.state.userList.map( user => {
      return(
            <div className="item-card">
                <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="del-wrap">
                    <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Between `v16.0.0 to 16.2.0`, you would return them as array like

```
displayUsers(){

    return ([
        <div className="item-card add" onClick = {this.addUser} >
           <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon"/>
           <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
       </div>,
      {this.state.userList.map( user => {
      return(
            <div className="item-card">
                <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="del-wrap">
                    <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })}
    ]
  )
}
```

and before v16, you would wrap them in a container div since you could only return a single element.

```
displayUsers(){

    return (
       <div>
        <div className="item-card add" onClick = {this.addUser} >
           <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon"/>
           <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
       </div>
      {this.state.userList.map( user => {
      return(
            <div className="item-card">
                <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="del-wrap">
                    <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest some where you can display without using `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: @stonerock you can wrap it in a div. The main idea is that a react component should render only 1 element. Within your map you are returning multiple nodes.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Awesome got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) returns the result of `displayUsers`.

Three answers:

- In React < v16, you have to wrap them in an element (for instance, a wrapper `div`).
- In React >= v16, you can return an array as you're doing, but you'll need to give them unique `key`s.
- In React >= v16.2, you can use `<React.Fragment>` instead and not give them `key`s.

#### Wrapper:

```
displayUsers(){
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.userList.map( user => {
            return(
                <div className="item-card">
                    <div className="info">    
                        <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="del-wrap">
                        <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### Array with unique `key`s:

```
displayUsers(){
    return this.state.userList.map(user => {
        return(
            <div key={user.???} className="item-card">
                <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="del-wrap">
                    <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

Note the `key={user.???}`, obviously pick a unique aspect of the `user` object to use.

#### `<React.Fragment>`:

```
displayUsers(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.userList.map(user => {
            return(
                <div key={user.???} className="item-card">
                    <div className="info">    
                        <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="del-wrap">
                        <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
displayUsers(){
 return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="item-card add" onClick = {this.addUser} >
    <img src={require("../../images/plus.svg")} className="plus-icon"/>
      <div className="lbl">Add a new User</div>
    </div>
  {
    this.state.userList.map( user => {
      return(
            <div className="item-card">
                <div className="info">    
                    <div className="username">Username: {user.userName}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="del-wrap">
                    <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })
 }
  </React.Fragment>
 )}
```